# How to make filtering in tastypie on virtual django model field (property)?

Tags: django, tastypie

I have the next django model where tracker_id is a virtual field:

```
class Failures(models.Model):
    _tracker_id = models.CharField('Tracker ID', max_length=50) 

    def __set_tracker_id(self, value):
        self._tracker_id = value

    def __get_tracker_id(self):
        issue = self.do_something(self._tracker_id)
        return issue

    tracker_id = property(__get_tracker_id, __set_tracker_id)
```

Also I have tastypie resource on it:

```
class FailuresResource(BasicResource):
    tracker_id = fields.CharField(attribute='tracker_id')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Failures.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']

        filtering = {
            'tracker_id': ALL,
        }
        excludes = ('_tracker_id', )
```

BUT! When I try to filter objects by tracker_id like this way

```
http://myhost/api/v1/failures/?tracker_id=123
```

I am getting error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'tracker_id' into field. Choices are: _tracker_id"

Is there anyway to make filtering by tracker_id instead internal field???

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering via `Meta` class is only available for real field.

Try to override `build_filters` function

```
def build_filters(self, filters=None):
    if filters is None:
        filters = {}

    orm_filters = super(FailuresResource, self).build_filters(filters)

    if 'tracker_id' in filters:
        # do your trick here
        orm_filters['_tracker_id'] = filters['tracker_id']

    return orm_filters
```

Don't forget to remove not-working filterings in your `Meta` class.

Comment: thank you. I thought in the same way. But it in my case it better to override apply_filters instead build_filters. There is come troubles with using build_filters with Resource inherited from ModelResource